# glReadPixels function returning error 1282 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working a simple DLL plugin where I call `glReadPixels` to return the pixels on the screen.When calling the function in the DLL, it failed to work with error `1282 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)`.

I decided to run the code as a console `EXE` program but the error is still there.

What am I doing wrong? I am using **Windows 10** with **Retina** screen and my code is below:

```
int x2 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int y2 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
GLvoid *imagePixelsArray = malloc((x2 *x2)*(y2* y2)*4);
glReadPixels(0, 0,x2,y2, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imagePixelsArray);
cout << "ERROR is " << glGetError() << endl;
```

I did `x2 *x2` and `(y2* y2)` because I am using Retina screen. Removing that didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: i've got a cookie that says you're not calling it inside of a valid GL context. and even if you are, ten cookies says it isn't a context that corresponds to the entire screen.

Comment: @JayKominek From Unity I am calling it from the OnPostRender function  and from what I understand, it is working for other people. Since it doesn't work, I decided to test it by itself with console app. Can you provide a link or an example? How do I call that from a valid GL context?  For the down-vote, I don't know why.

Comment: Does a [`wglGetCurrentContext()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) right before `glReadPixels()` return something other than `NULL`?

Comment: @genpfault I did `cout << wglGetCurrentContext()` and got 00000000. That looks like null to me. What do you think?

Comment: @Programmer unity is doing all kinds of stuff behind the scenes. If it has initialized GL and then run your code when a GL context is valid, then you've got a shot at this working. GL code pulled completely out of context (in the non-technical sense of the word) cannot be expected to behave the same, because of the nature of OpenGL. sticking it in a console app without any setup just can't work. (that's probably where the downvotes were coming from. wasn't me. i didn't even vote to close.)

Comment: Looks pretty null to me too.  You're sure Unity is using its OpenGL renderer and not the Direct3D one?

Comment: @genpfault I thought you can take screenshot of the system screen with `glReadPixels`. Now I realized you can't. You can only take screenshot of the running app. I already can take screenshot with a windows api in c++ but I wanted to use opengl for portability reasons. I even changed the render to OpenGL Core. I will stick with the windows api because that opengl function is not exactly what I thought it was. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JayKominek I know you didn't downvote. I am just asking to know why people down-voted. Thanks for explaining that that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am working a simple DLL plugin where I call glReadPixels to return the pixels on the screen.

Are you trying to take a screenshot? Your code snippet looks like you try to. Here's the thing about OpenGL's `glReadPixels`:

**You can't take screenshots with *glReadPixels*!**

Up until, including Windows-XP some OpenGL implementation had the behaviour that if you created a full screen window without a background brush set created an OpenGL context and made it current on it, you may actually end up with a screenshot by virtue of the graphics driver not initializing the window's framebuffer thus leaving the screen contents as "garbage" you could grab.

However this is essentially *undefined behaviour* and *glReadPixels is defined to deliver pixels created with OpenGL only.*

As of Windows Vista windows are composited and no longer share a common on-screen framebuffer and this wonky way of creating screenshots no longer works. It never worked that way for MacOS-X and in X11 even before compositing was a thing it more often than not did not work.

Comment: Yes, it I am using it as a way to get a screenshot. I am doing this on Windows not on Mac. This seems to work for other people here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/465409/reading-from-a-rendertexture-is-slow-how-to-improv.html The only problem they had is when running it on Android but it should work.

Comment: @Programmer The answers.unity3d OP was trying to read from a texture that they rendered to, not the entire screen. OpenGL cannot be used to do full screengrab that includes other windows; you need OS-specific APIs for this.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo  I think I read the thing wrong. Thanks for letting me know about that. I think this is what I am looking for.